# Add parameter to Flask decorator

Tags: python, flask

I use a snippet for Flask that creates a decorator for handling HTTP Basic Auth:

```
def requires_auth(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        auth = request.authorization
        if not auth or not check_auth(auth.username, auth.password):
            return authenticate()
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated
```

This decorator does not allow a parameter to be passed. I would like to change that, how can I do it?
I have been checking other SO questions about decorators, but still I cannot get this working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using a decorator, the object specified on the line preceding the function (or class) definition must be a function (or other callable object) that takes a function (or class) and returns a function (or class).

So that means that if you want to pass an argument to a decorator, then the following line:

```
@requires_auth("admin")
```

must denote a function (or other callable object). In other words, `requires_auth("admin")` is executed, and the *result* of this call is used to decorate the function (or class) that follows.

Which is to say, the function that accepts the arguments must *return* a function that actually does the decorating!

Something like this, then:

```
def requires_auth(user):

    def decorator(f):
        # the actual decorator, which may use the variable "user"
        # (basically everything you've written, including the wrapper)

    return decorator
```

You can also write it in the form of a class.  The class's `__init__` method will accept the arguments, and its `__call__` method will accept the function/class to be decorated. That is, `requires_auth("admin")` creates an instance of the object, and the instance is then passed the function being decorated and does the job.

```
class requires_auth:

    def __init__(self, user):
         self.user = user

    def __call__(self, f):
         # your decorator as above, referring to "self.user" for the arg
```